# How to Hide the Scroll bar in the Iphone (webview)

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css

I am doing a web view Iphone app, and I am using Jquery scroll. but on the Iphone there is scroll bar appear. how can I hide it.

here is the link

http://gridberry.com/iphone/

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but try changing your settings like this:

```
$(function(o){  
    o = $("#overscroll").overscroll({
        cancelOn: '.no-drag',
        persistThumbs: true,
        showThumbs: false,
        scrollLeft: 200
    }).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend', function(event){
        //
    });
});
```

If that does not work (I am not 100% sure looking at the source), I know a more hackish way this can be done. Let me know.

Comment: unfortunately, the scroll bar still appears in the Iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for hide the scroll bar into the browser.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

or

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```